# ssh launch of jenkins slave stalls jenkins start

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this issue. Jenkins on restarts takes forever and from the logs I can see that its sitting trying to launch the slave

```
06/25/15 14:03:34] SSH Launch of Slave1 on dom-jenkins-sl1.cloud.dev.phx3.gdg failed in 179,907 ms

Jun 25, 2015 2:05:06 PM hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer tryReconnect
INFO: Attempting to reconnect Slave1
Jun 25, 2015 2:05:07 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 33090
Jun 25, 2015 2:05:07 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Jun 25, 2015 2:05:07 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.skipcert.ItemListenerImpl onLoaded
INFO: Bypassing certificate check
Jun 25, 2015 2:05:08 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
[06/25/15 14:05:08] SSH Launch of Slave1 on dom-jenkins-sl1.cloud.dev.phx3.gdg completed in 1,923 ms
```

And yet on the second try 2 minutes later it works just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: a shot in the dark: try a `stop+pause+start` sequence instead of just `restart`, I noticed in linux occasionally *some* servers have trouble re-opening the same IP sockets properly if that follows too closely an abrupt server demise (tens of seconds!).

Comment: Ah, I bet you're right. I'll give that a shot, thanks!